# How can I fix this bathroom drain set up?

Tags: plumbing, drain

[image]Currently s trap with flexy tube and leak where pvc goes into metal pipe. I am not super concerned with s trap at the moment but would like a better set up and no leaks. I am just not sure the best way to go about it [image]

Edit - added a picture of where it’s leaking, where the pvc goes into the metal pipe. From what I can tell it is just shoved into the metal pipe, no gasket or anything. So I assume I need some kind of gasket? Not a joke, just trying to diy and make it drain efficiently without leaks. Thank you

Comment: What is your goal?? (What are you trying to fix? Is there something broken?). You mentioned you're not concerned with the S trap, so this question seems more like a puzzle.

Comment: I think this is a joke or some type of test.  The setup should be leaking badly.  The second section of the "S" trap is a ptrap upside down and the flange at the end means it must only be sitting on the first part of the ptrap from the sink.  I don't see how any of this doesn't leak.

Comment: Make sure the compression ring is facing the right direction.  In your case, I believe the flat end should face up and the tapered end should face down.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently horrific with this setup.  A lot of people don't like flex tube, and I wouldn't choose it if I was doing this from scratch, but there's no gain from just replacing it for the sake of it.  It doesn't look elegant but this is in a cupboard right, so do you care?

Why not focus on the leaks?

Which end is leaking?  It's hard to see what's going on at the far end where the PVC joins a dark poorly lit pipe.  If that end is leaking, please take a better picture of it.  If it's the tail pipe end, open the connector and make sure a correctly sized compression washer is used (1-1/4, 1-1/2, or an adapting ring from one to the other) and is seating properly.

Answer (score 0):

Metal pipe to PVC (S-trap) needs new seal.

Get a thicker o-ring to replace current seal. Or use some silicone or even plumber putty to seal it. Since there is no pressure both will work. I would prefer plumber putty since it is easy to remove if you have to.

Second:

The flexible tube connection from S-trap to the straight pipe could be overcome.

Loosen the nuts (just loosen do not unscrew). Now try to adjust the S-trap so you could use new (longer) straight pipe, thus eliminating the flexible tube two possible leak connections.

Comment: Genuinely curious: Where would a "new (longer) straight pipe" go in order to eliminate the flex pipe? Looks to me like the trap doesn't have enough movement to get to a vertical position over the drain stub out in the floor, so I'd think it would need a horizontal trap arm to a 90°. i.e. a new P-trap instead of the S-trap installed. Is that what you meant?